# i want to obtain max value of a column depending on two other columns and for the forth column the value of the most repeated number

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark-pandas, pyspark-schema

I've got this dataframe

```
df1 = spark.createDataFrame([
    ('c', 'd', 3.0, 4),
    ('c', 'd', 7.3, 8),
    ('c', 'd', 7.3, 2),
    ('c', 'd', 7.3, 8),
    ('e', 'f', 6.0, 3),
    ('e', 'f', 6.0, 8),
    ('e', 'f', 6.0, 3),
    ('c', 'j', 4.2, 3),
    ('c', 'j', 4.3, 9),
], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
df1.show()
+---+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  c|  d|
+---+---+---+---+
|  c|  d|3.0|  4|
|  c|  d|7.3|  8|
|  c|  d|7.3|  2|
|  c|  d|7.3|  8|
|  e|  f|6.0|  3|
|  e|  f|6.0|  8|
|  e|  f|6.0|  3|
|  c|  j|4.2|  3|
|  c|  j|4.3|  9|
+---+---+---+---+
```

i did this to get the max of c of the couple a and b

```
df2 = df1.groupBy('a', 'b').agg(F.max('c').alias('c_max')).select(
        F.col('a'),
        F.col('b'),
        F.col('c_max').alias('c')
    )
df2.show()
+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  c|
+---+---+---+
|  e|  f|6.0|
|  c|  d|7.3|
|  c|  j|4.3|
+---+---+---+
```

but now i need to get the values of d that should be

```
+---+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  c|  d|
+---+---+---+---+
|  c|  d|7.3|  8|
|  e|  f|6.0|  3|
|  c|  j|4.3|  9|
+---+---+---+---+
```

i tried to do an inner join between df1 and df2 but that didn't work:

```
condition = [df1.a ==  df2.a, df1.b ==  df2.b, df1.c ==  df2.c]
df3 = df1.join(df2,condition,"inner")
df3.show()
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  c|  d|  a|  b|  c|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|  c|  d|7.3|  8|  c|  d|7.3|
|  c|  d|7.3|  8|  c|  d|7.3|
|  c|  d|7.3|  2|  c|  d|7.3|
|  e|  f|6.0|  3|  e|  f|6.0|
|  e|  f|6.0|  8|  e|  f|6.0|
|  e|  f|6.0|  3|  e|  f|6.0|
|  c|  j|4.3|  9|  c|  j|4.3|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

i'm a beginner in pyspark, so please i need a little help to figure this out

Comment: for the d column, what is the logic that "9" is chosen over "3" for row3 (c&j)?  More generally, what is the logic for tie breaker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can "zip" `d` and count of `d` and aggregate as usual to keep the frequency

```py
df3 = (df1
    .groupBy('a', 'b', 'd')
    .agg(F.count('*').alias('d_count'))
    .groupBy('a', 'b')
    .agg(F.max(F.array('d_count', 'd')).alias('d_freq'))
    .select('a', 'b', F.col('d_freq')[1].alias('d'))
)

+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  d|
+---+---+---+
|  c|  d|  8|
|  c|  j|  9|
|  e|  f|  3|
+---+---+---+
```

Now join both your `df2` and this new `df3` will give your desired output.

```py
df2.join(df3, on=['a', 'b']).show()
+---+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  c|  d|
+---+---+---+---+
|  c|  d|7.3|  8|
|  c|  j|4.3|  9|
|  e|  f|6.0|  3|
+---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: OP is asking for "most repeated number" not max for d.

Comment: It's max for `c`, `d`'s value OP wants is attached to that max `c`

Comment: I saw the dataframe at "now i need to get the values of d that should be".  it is 8, 3, 9.  not 8, 9, 8 for d.  Also, title says for the fourth column, most repeated number.

Comment: Ah I think you're right! My bad

Comment: np!  I still don't know what OP wants for the tie breaker though.

Comment: maybe they don't even care (yet) :)

Comment: thank you for all your help ^^, this was given for me to do and it's been three days that i'm trying and can't seem to find the answer, i think it's impossible to do, if i wanted the max of d and c that would be  so much easier but unfortunatly it's not the case

Comment: @sunny I updated my answer

Comment: thank you for all your efforts, it did work 

Answer (score 0):

You can first count the frequency and assign the order value by  sorting them in descending order. Then, get the first value where the order is 1.

This does not deal with tie breaking, if there are tie in the top frequency, this will pick whatever (non-deterministic).

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df1 = (df1.withColumn('d_count', F.count('*').over(Window.partitionBy(['a', 'b', 'd'])))
 .withColumn('d_order', F.row_number().over(Window.partitionBy(['a', 'b']).orderBy(F.desc('d_count'))))
 .groupby(['a', 'b'])
 .agg(
   F.max('c').alias('c'),
   F.first(F.when(F.col('d_order') == 1, F.col('d'))).alias('d'))
)
```

```
# df1.show()

+---+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  c|  d|
+---+---+---+---+
|  e|  f|6.0|  3|
|  c|  d|7.3|  8|
|  c|  j|4.3|  9|
+---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: thank you a lot @Emma , sorry i'm new to stackoverflow so i just saw your answer, i tested it and it does work !, i think yours is the best option since we will create only one dataframe and it's a great way for me to try to understand window functions and learn how to use them